# Getting MS error in installation of jsdom - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom, node.js-domains

I am installing jsdom. I am following http://www.steveworkman.com/node-js/2012/installing-jsdom-on-windows/ but I am getting:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform
.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'contextify.vcxproj' is
 invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are tryin
g to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default
Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [c:\wamp\www\node_modules\context
ify\build\contextify.vcxproj]
```

Am I able to understand why I'm getting this? And what is MSB8007?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like gyp tries to build for x64 (most likely because you have node-x64 installed) and you don't have the x64 C++-Compiler in Visual Studio installed. Either try modifying your VS Installation to include the x64 toolchain, or try using/installing a 32bit node.